# Looking for a shell one-liner to display the age of a file (in days)

Tags: linux, command-line

I'd like to see the age of a file (time since last modification) in some human-friendly units (bonus points for things like "yesterday", "2 days ago", "3 years ago", although just a number of days would be sufficient).

Is there a shell one-liner that's simple enough to memorize and type on demand?  Is there a tool (packaged for Debian/Ubuntu)?  Do I write a custom shell script to do some arithmetic and install it on all the servers I have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will display a file's age in days:

```
age () { stat=$(stat --printf="%Y %F\n" "$1"); echo "The ${stat#* } '$1' is $((($(date +%s) - ${stat%% *})/86400)) days old."; }
```

Examples:

```
$ age foo
The regular file 'foo' is 41 days old.
$ age ../bar
The directory '../bar' is 296 days old.
$ age /path/to/baz
The symbolic link '/path/to/baz' is 207 days old.
```

Further refinement could be done to show the age in months, years, etc.

Comment: you take "one-liner" far to serious :)

Comment: nice one, but this is definitely option (C), shell script; not option (A), something I could memorize

Comment: @Marius: Well, the short version that just prints the number of days alone would be `echo $((($(date +%s) - $(stat --printf="%Y" filename))/86400))` which may not be easy to memorize, but all you really need to memorize is the principle of how it works. It's easy enough to reconstruct on that basis.

Comment: In which case $(date +%s -r filename) may be easier to remember than $(stat ...).

Comment: I suppose I could manage to remember `$[(\`date +%s\`-\`date +%s -r filename\`)/86400]`.

Comment: @Marius: Nice one on the `date -r`! I missed that. The `$[]` form is deprecated - use `$(())` instead. And `$()` is [preferred over backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). `echo $((($(date +%s)-$(date +%s -r filename))/86400))`

Answer (score 1):

It close enough to produce a good human readable date ! There is an option for ls `--time-style`. That let you format the date that will be displayed.

Example

```
 ls -l --time-style="+%b %_d %Y"

 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 11359620 Jul 20 2010 file.ext
```

To prevent typing this hung command you can alias it in your .bashrc file.